# Dual Channel Reading with 16 bit AD7705(SPI)

Tags: arduino-nano, spi, adc

I want to read 2 separate voltage readings by AD7705 ADC and send the data to Arduino(Master). What is the correct program flow should I implement to get dual-channel operation working. How data will be sent to master when both the channels are converting the voltage.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: the data would be sent one bit at a time, since the data path is serial ... it is unclear what you are asking

Comment: Correct flow? Switch to channel 1, perform conversion, read data... Same for the second channel. And repeat

Comment: "How data will be sent to master" is controlled by the master. That's why it is called *master*. What's your question/problem?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I understood.